# Trying to pass an array through Google App Script to create a Data Table

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to pass an array through Google App Script to create a data table to then build a chart to place in a slide. However I seem to be coming across some issues and cannot seem to use the array to build out the table. Can anyone assist? Thanks!

```
function test2() {

    var url = 'INSERT URL'; // insert url
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url));


var sampleData = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Year")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses")
    .addRow()
    .addRow()
    .addRow()
    .addRow()
    .setValue(contents)
    .build();

    Logger.log(sampleData);

var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
    .setTitle('Sales & Expenses')
    .setXAxisTitle('Year')
    .setYAxisTitle('Amount (USD)')
    .setDimensions(300, 300)
    .setDataTable(sampleData)
    .build();

var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlideById('INSERT ID');

slide.insertImage(chart);

}
```

I tried parsing the csv into an array but it still won't resolve into a data table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your showing script is modified, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function test2() {
  var url = 'INSERT URL'; // insert url
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()); // or var [,...contents] = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

  var sampleData = Charts.newDataTable()
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Year")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Sales")
    .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Expenses");
  contents.forEach(r => sampleData.addRow(r));
  Logger.log(sampleData);

  var chart = Charts.newColumnChart()
    .setTitle('Sales & Expenses')
    .setXAxisTitle('Year')
    .setYAxisTitle('Amount (USD)')
    .setDimensions(300, 300)
    .setDataTable(sampleData.build())
    .build();

  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlideById('INSERT ID');
  slide.insertImage(chart);
}
```

#### Note:

- This modification supposes that your 2-dimensional array of `var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());` is a valid value. Please be careful about this.
- If your value of `contents` has 1st header row, an error related to the value type might occur. Please be careful about this. At that time, please modify it to `var [,...contents] = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());` and test it again.

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)